# understanding of SAS Macro code

Tags: statistics, sas

I am looking into a SAS macro code that was written by my senior for a process. I couldn't understand the code written. in one of the macro code it was written as

```
%macro1(macro2(pm1, pm2, pm3))
```

after this statement `%macro2` is written with some other calculations.

can any one help me in understanding the processing of the code mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that your syntax that you submit on StackOverflow is correct - you have one unclosed parenthesis and the code snippet should look like that:

```
%macro1(macro2(pm1, pm2, pm3))
```

The code that you've presented is easy to achieve.

```
%macro t1(arg);
    %put NOTE: t1; 
    %&arg.; 
%mend t1;

%macro t2(arg2);
    %put NOTE: t2;    
    %put NOTE: Arg 2 = &arg2.;    
%mend t2;

%t1(t2(test));
```

Output:

```
NOTE: t1
NOTE: t2
NOTE: Arg 2 = test
```

Basically, you are passing the string to invoke an inner macro as a argument to the outer macro. You can reference the inner macro by an *ampersand* sign. In the code snippet above, I've created two macros, and the **t1** macro is referencing the argument like this:

```
%&arg.;
```

It resolves to:

```
MLOGIC(T1):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(T1):  Parameter ARG has value t2(test)
MLOGIC(T1):  %PUT NOTE: t1
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable ARG resolves to t2(test)
MLOGIC(T2):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(T2):  Parameter ARG2 has value test
```

And that allows the code to run properly - to invoke a macro as an argument of another macro.